# Voice-activated dialer for Android that is privacy sensitive (voice command)

Tags: android, privacy, contact-manager, voice-command, voice-recognition

Can anyone recommend a voice-activated dialer for Android that does not upload all your contacts to an external server?

I want to be able to simple say "Call electrician" and have it call my electrician, without having to send a list of all my contacts to some external (remote) server.

Prefer gratis, but any cost is fine.

Comment: What about "voice recognition data" being uploaded? Pure on-device voice recognition apps are still rare (though I wonder why, as even my old Nokia E61 was capable of "voice dialing" – and my old i386 with OS/2 of dictation and more). Google usually does that online, and most "alternative assistants" as well.

Comment: @Izzy Do you know of any that are purely offline ("on-device")?

Comment: Not by own experience. Dragon Assistant is said to have that capability, and utter! – both apps haven't been updated for at least 2 resp. 3 years.

Comment: Thanks.  I tried Dragon in the past, and I can't remember why I uninstalled it (might have been a TOS issue).  IIRC, I also tried utter! and uninstalled it as well.  It's odd that these applications don't get updated, as there is probably significant demand.

Comment: Demand on my end as well. But it has to be FOSS. Proprietary vendors might *say* they care for privacy – but you can never be sure whose they mean. I'd rather they do the recognition only (so they'd need just microphone and maybe storage), leaving the job-2-b-done to some other app like Tasker, Llama, you-name-it – so we can pick the modules we trust … Speaking of which: Do you sync with Google (eeek!)? Then Tasker+AutoVoice (using Google voice recognition) could do the trick (well, I expect Google Now would not be acceptable ;)

Comment: @Izzy Yes, every company claims "privacy" and "security" but few deliver.  I definitely don't sync with Google.

Comment: @Izzy Over the last 2+ years, have you found any solutions?

Comment: Unfortunately not. But I've not actively checked, admittedly.